# Clicking on the collapsed notification message app will restart

Tags: android, notifications

I have reviewed a lot of information on this issue, but no one can solved it.

On android 7.0 devices,when using NotificationManager to send more than 5 messages, all messages will be collapsed.

[Please click on the image to see the message is collapsed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U66kK.png)

When I click on this collapsed notification bar message, my app will be rebooted into the login activity even if my app is logged in and running in the foreground.This is terrible.If I click on a single notification bar message, then it will enter the activity normally.

How to set the notification bar message to not collapse or when I click on the collapsed notification bar message, do not restart the app.
this is my code:

```
Intent notifyIntent;
PendingIntent appIntent;
notifyIntent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
notifyIntent.putExtra("content", contentJson);
appIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            noticeId, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "program").setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(iconId)
            .setContentTitle(notifyTitle)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setNumber(noticeId)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setContentIntent(appIntent);
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setColorized(true);
    Notification myNoti = builder.build();
    myNoti.flags = NotificationCompat.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    if (noticeId > 40) {
        noticeId = 0;
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }
    notificationManager.notify(noticeId, myNoti);
```

I set TestActivity

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, not what I thought. App is not restarted.Only LoginActivity was recreated once and placed on the top of the stack.I am worried that other people have the same thoughts as me and think that the APP has been restarted,So I won’t change this question.I hope to help people who have this problem.I will put the solution below.

When you click on the collapsed notification bar message, assume your LoginAtivity has been recreated.You need to write the following code in the onCreate of LoginActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}
```

isTaskRoot() will detect if this class is at the root of the stack.If not, then finish.

Note that if you have logic in onDestory, use isTaskToot() to determine,for example:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        //your code
    }
}
```